# LibGDX mirroring/flipping a Stage for use as Splitscreen

Tags: libgdx, mirroring, split-screen

What I want to do:
I'd like to use two Stages for a Splitscreen game. With different Stages I can control Input and other things separately. One Stage is mirrored/flipped so that the players can sit opposite to each other.

The problem:
Unfortunately my knowledge about Stages/Viewports/Cameras is not good enough yet to solve this problem. I tried several things but did not get a satisfying solution.

Is there anybody who can give me some hints or an example which help me to find a way to a solution?
Thanks!

(click the image link below for a visual draft)

[split-stage-draft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWdYK.png)

Comment: Afaik there is no mirroring of a stage. Why don't you just make 2 stages? Create a class that functions as a half screen and when you need two players you put these next to eachother? But then I have absolutely no experience with duel screen multiplayer games. Maybe ask on IRC?

Comment: You can do this if not using the UI widgets of scene2d. You must code a Viewport for each half of the screen. The viewport must crop the GL Viewport to the half of the screen you want. For the top, you also should rotate the camera 180 degrees about the z axis.

Comment: Alternatively, you could make the top viewport a standard ExtendViewport and draw it to a FrameBuffer and then draw the FrameBuffer's texture to the top of the screen. Then you could use the UI stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I managed to rotate the upper stage by modifying the up vector of the camera of the viewport. 
Unfortunately I still have problems to separate the screen for the two stages correctly (e.g. by using the bounds of the viewports of the stages). They are drawn "overlaying" each other instead of one stage drawn on the upper half and the other stage drawn on the lower half of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

mirroring: 
using the up vector of the cam of the viewport of the stage (see comment above)

screen separation: 
using 
`Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), halfScreenHeight);` (stage 1) and `Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, halfScreenHeight, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), halfScreenHeight);` (stage 2) to define the drawing area for each stage before calling draw()